# In what order should statically linked libraries for libavdevice and x11 be linked?

Tags: c++, linux, ffmpeg, static-libraries, x11

Currently having a problem with statically linking my project. After adding avdevice as statically linked I received the following error.

> :-1: error:
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.a(XShm.o):
>   undefined reference to symbol '_XGetBitsPerPixel'

The following is a snippet of the libraries I've added statically.

```
LIBS += -L"/usr/local/lib" \
            -L"/usr/local/lib64" \
            -lm -lz -llzma -lass -lfreetype -lmp3lame -ltheora -lvorbis -lvorbisenc -lva -lva-drm -lva-x11 -ldrm -logg -lvpx -lopenh264 -lavformat -lavcodec -lswscale -lavutil -lavfilter -lswresample -lavdevice -lX11 -lXfixes -lXext -lxcb -lXdmcp -lXau \
```

I've tried moving -lXext in front of -lX11 but get a whole bunch of undefined references such as

```
error: undefined reference to `uncompress'
```

In what order do these statically linked libraries need to be in for the project to compile?

Comment: Related, `-Wl,--start-group -lm -lz -llzma ... -lxcb -lXdmcp -lXau -Wl,--end-group` will create a group so you don't need to worry about order. The libraries in the group are searched repeatedly until no new undefined references are created. Also see the [`ld(1)` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld).

Comment: @jww I think this should be an answer. While it does not answer the direct question _In what order do these statically linked libraries need to be?_, it answer the second part _for the project to compile?_

Answer (score 1):

The **linkers algorithm for resolving external references** works as follows:

1. Scan .o files and .a files in the command line order
2. During the scan, keep a list of the current unresolved references
3. As each new .o or .a file, obj, is encountered, try to resolve each unresolved reference in the list against the symbols defined in obj
4. If any entries in the unresolved list at end of scan, then throw an error

In your case this means when moving `-lXext` in front of `-lX11`, `uncompressed` will stay unresolved as `uncompressed` wasn't part of the list of unresolved references when `-lXext` was being scanned. As @jww pointed out in the comments, you can **create a  group** to get rid of the problem as you are repeatedly trying to resolve each unresolved reference with each new added library, which means the order doesn't matter. 
This can be done in the following way: `-Wl,--start-group lib.o ... list.o -Wl,--end-group`, where you substitute `lib.o ... list.o` with your libraries above.